# displaying text with html tags as plain text in android

Tags: android, html

I am trying to display text with html tags as plain text in my android app. I have tried using some of the html methods and they end up shoeing a blank space instead of my text.

```
 final ptaModel current = mDataList.get(position);

    Spanned content;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    {
        content = Html.fromHtml(current.getContent(), FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
    }
    else
    {
        content = Html.fromHtml(current.getContent());
    }

    holder.date.setText(current.getDate());
    holder.minutes.setText(content);
    holder.title.setText(current.getTitle());
```

I found an answer that said to use the code above, but i end up getting an empty textview instead of plain text.

This is the content i am receiving with html tags:

```
"content":"<p>&nbsp;<\/p><p>Attendees:<\/p><p> <br><\/p><p>Suzy Bullett, Lisa Wagner, Jamie Flint,
 Camilla Logeske, Jennifer Legault, Emily Hidalgo<\/p><p> <br><\/p><p>&nbsp;<\/p><p>
  <br><\/p><p>Meeting called to order at 7:30am<\/p><p> <br><\/p><p>&nbsp;<\/p><p> 
  <br><\/p><p><b style=\"bidi-font-weight:normal\">New Business-<\/b><\/p><p> <br><\/p>
  <p class=c1 style=\"text-indent:-.25in;list:l1 level1 lfo1\">1.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   How to spend money made from Fall Fundraiser <\/p><p> <br><\/p>
   <p class=c2 style=\"margin-left:.75in;add-space: auto;text-indent:-.25in;list:l0 level1 lfo2\">
   A.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Water bottle filler $1000 (possibly pay for with jogathon funds)<\/p><p> 
   <br><\/p><p class=c2 style=\"margin-left:.75in;add-space: auto;text-indent:-.25in;list:l0 level1 lfo2\">B.
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Chrome book cart $1500, $400 for Chrome Books<\/p><p> <br><\/p>
   <p class=c2 style=\"margin-left:.75in;add-space: auto;text-indent:-.25in;list:l0 level1 lfo2\">
   C.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Teacher laptops, 8 needed<\/p><p> <br><\/p>
   <p class=c2 style=\"margin-left:.75in;add-space: auto;text-indent:-.25in;list:l0 level1 lfo2\">
   D.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; AR $4000<\/p><p> <br><\/p><p class=c2 style=\"text-indent:-.25in;list:l1 level1 lfo1\">
   2.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; PTA membership drive, end home form and put on Facebook<\/p><p>
    <br><\/p><p class=c2 style=\"text-indent:-.25in;list:l1 level1 lfo1\">3.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    Fall Carnival<\/p><p> <br><\/p><p class=c2 style=\"margin-left:.75in;add-space: auto;text-indent:-.25in;list:l2 
    level1 lfo3\">A.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; First meeting 9\/22<\/p><p> <br><\/p>
    <p class=c2 style=\"margin-left:.75in;add-space: auto;text-indent:-.25in;list:l2 level1 lfo3\">
    B.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Tickets<\/p><p> <br><\/p><p class=c2 style=\"margin-left:.75in;add-space:
     auto;text-indent:-.25in;list:l2 level1 lfo3\">C.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Dinner, Amy Burrows<\/p><p>
      <br><\/p><p class=c2 style=\"margin-left:.75in;add-space: auto;text-indent:-.25in;list:l2 level1 lfo3\">D.
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Raffle <\/p><p> <br><\/p><p class=c2 style=\"margin-left:.75in;add-space: 
      auto;text-indent:-.25in;list:l2 level1 lfo3\">E.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Auction<\/p><p> <br>
      <\/p><p class=c2 style=\"margin-left:.75in;add-space: auto;text-indent:-.25in;list:l2 level1 lfo3\">
      F.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Games\/redemption center<\/p><p> <br><\/p><p class=c2 style=\"margin-l
      eft:.75in;add-space: auto;text-indent:-.25in;list:l2 level1 lfo3\">G.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Cake walk<
      \/p><p> <br><\/p><p class=c2 style=\"margin-left:.75in;add-space: auto;text-indent:-.25in;list:l2 level1 lfo3\"
      >H.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Talked about asking for monetary donations instead of doing baskets, try to ra
      ise the money for teacher laptops this way.<\/p><p> <br><\/p><p class=c2 style=\"text-indent:-.25in;list:l1 leve
      l1 lfo1\">4.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Upgrade VITAL room computer<\/p><p> <br><\/p><p class=c2 style
      =\"text-indent:-.25in;list:l1 level1 lfo1\">5.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Add babysitters for kindergar
      ten back to school night to budget<\/p><p> <br><\/p><p class=c3 style=\"text-indent:-.25in;list:l1 level1 lfo1\">
      6.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Treasurer’s report- Jamie<\/p><p> <br><\/p><p style=\"margin-left:.25in\">
      &nbsp;<\/p><p> <br><\/p><p style=\"margin-left:.25in\">Meeting Adjourned 8:20<\/p><p> <br"}
```

Comment: Can you show what is coming in current.getContent()?

Comment: @AbdullahMehmood i have added it

Comment: As i see your content is using style class that is not familiar for Html class in android.

Comment: @AbdullahMehmood alright, thank you for that. i will have the content sent as plain text instaed